# As of the 2014 NEC code do tamper resistant receptacles need to be installed on a GFCI circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ground

Replacing 2 prong with 3 prong. Want to protect the entire circuit with a GFCI. 
Do the outlets I replace have to be tamper resistant if they are protected by a GFCI?

Comment: Good question... Were these non-tamper-resistant receptacles installed prior to NEC 2014's effective date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest code yes even gfci protected outlets require the tamper resistance feature. In fact outdoor gfci outlets that are weather resistant or stamped WR need the tamper resistant feature also. Got hit on that one last year.